# Python 3.7.4 Module Not Found Error: No module named 'faceboook'

Tags: python, facebook

```
C:\Users\test>pip install facebook-sdk

Requirement already satisfied: facebook-sdk in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from facebook-sdk) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (2.8)
```

Even i check pip3.7, the result was the same.

```
C:\Users\barry.h.yu>pip3.7 install facebook-sdk
Requirement already satisfied: facebook-sdk in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from facebook-sdk) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests->facebook-sdk) (2019.9.11)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
import faceboook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='Hide', version='4.0')

print(post['message'])
```

I tried to uninstall facebook in pip and re-install, the result was still the same.

Error message:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\barry.h.yu\Desktop\Facebook.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\barry.h.yu\Desktop\Facebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    import faceboook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faceboook'
>>>
```

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and `pip` install for one Python but you run code with other Python. On Linux you could have `pip3.7` to install module for Python 3.7. Or you can do `python3.7 -m pip install ...`

Comment: Just to make sure, did you install the `facebook-sdk` package in `pip`?

Comment: Are you sure `facebook-sdk` is the same module as `facebook`?

Comment: Installed facebook-sdk package in pip as above cmd result

Comment: which pip request should i request if i want to test facebook graph API

Comment: first show full error message in question.

Comment: after installing module run `import facebook` to test it. If it doesn't work then check your Python - `python -V` - maybe you doesn't use 3.7 to run code and then better use `python -m pip install ...` to install it in correct python.